# Request method options when i make get request

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm having problem in VueJs. When I try to set header (I will send JWT token in it) developer tools always show, that this request is OPTIONS. I was checking [documentation](http://garywhat.leanote.com/post/vue-resource-HTTP-Requests-Response-Documentation) and as far as I see, this is the proper way of implementation, so what I'm missing?.

```
getCurrentUser() {
    let token = this.$jwt.getToken();
    if (token) {
        let jwtPayloadDecoder = require('jwt-payload-decoder');
        let payload = jwtPayloadDecoder.getPayload(token);
        this.$http.get(this.$apiUrl + `rest/api/public/User/user/` + payload.id_user, {
            headers: {
                'jwtToken': token,
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.statusText === 'OK') {
                flash('Got user', 'success');
            }
        })
        .catch(e => {
            flash('Something is wrong. Please try again later.', 'error');
        });
    } else this.$router.push('/');
},
```

And this is what I view in developer tools in chrome
[image]

My appache httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</IfModule>
```

If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a [CORS issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: You better use axios. It is as simple as http resources but much better. Also as the previous comment suggests check CORS request, but probably not because you are fetching an api and the header should suffice

Comment: i have Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in my apache.conf

Comment: @Valor_ you need to also tell cors what methods to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser sends a preflight request with method OPTIONS that seems to be rejected by your Webserver. If you respond to OPTIONS calls with 200 and the correct access-control headers from your server it should send the correct request afterwards.

Have a look at preflight requests: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request
and CORS in general for further information.